# Sending bulk sms to clients. what kind of data storage should i prefer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I did one app using shared preference where storage capacity is too low just adding mobile IMEI no and OTP no etc., Now i plan to create the appln which is used to send sms to bulk number. but in the beginning i got stuck whether its good to used **SHARED PREFERENCE**. Any suggestion please let me know. thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While dealing with bigger sets of data, using the database is always a better approach